# Refresh Guava Cache on external notification

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am using Guava cache for caching data from database. Now I have one problem and help will be highly appreciated. I have to update or refresh cash entries on external notification. I am using some third party interface which will notify me when anything new will happen in data base and i have to refresh my cache on that notification. so in short i will receive notification and on that notification i have to refresh my guava cache. so please let me know how it will possible and short example or java source code will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to `cache.put(key, newValue)` upon notification. Am I missing something here?